# show/hide multiple divs on clicking other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a script for my webpage where I want to show and hide some divs by clicking on anchor tags as given on this link . This is exactly what i was looking for but  its not working as i copy it on my web page.

May be i have to add some jquery plugin for this or any other script source please . Everything is working on example but not on my page please tell me where am i missing something

**here is js fiddle:**
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/421/)

**here is script code**

```
$('.targetDiv').hide();
$('.targetDiv').first().show();
$('.showSingle').first().addClass('selected');
$('.showSingle').click(function () {
$('.targetDiv').hide();
$('.showSingle').removeClass('selected');
$('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
$(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
$("a").click(function(){
$(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");

var pullNumber = $(this).attr("target");

$("#div"+pullNumber).show().siblings(".targetDiv").hide();

});

</script>

<style>
.buttons .selected {
color: red;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>



<div class="buttons">
<a  class="showSingle" target="1">Option 1</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="2">Option 2</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="3">Option 3</a>
<a  class="showSingle" target="4">Option 4</a>
</div>

<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum 4</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then what is the problem? Working in fiddle.

Comment: Is jQuery properly linked on your page? Could you show us your webpage? (Is it online?)

Comment: Those should be `<button>`s, not `<a>`s (the `<a>`s don't have `href`s). Instead of `target` attr you should be using `data-target` (for valid HTML).

Comment: no its on localhost wamp server ,I've added all the content on single page @royhowie

Comment: but anchor tag is working on fiddle then why use buttons @danielnixon

Comment: Because *semantically* they're buttons, not links. Also `<a>` tags without `href` attributes have keyboard accessibility issues.

Comment: SEE MY UPDATE  this is how am i using the whole code

Comment: @Darkknight look at my update below, from your updated code it looks like your script renders before the HTML/CSS thus you're click handler is not binding correctly.

Comment: @danielnixon should i use javascript:void(0); something like this ??

Comment: That will fix the keyboard accessibility, but you're still better off with a real `<button>`. If you insist on using an anchor tag, you need to make sure you have a (non-empty) `href` attr. You should probably also add a `role="button"` attr to override the `<a>` tag's link semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write this with less code by chaining things together and using some CSS like so:

**JS**

```
$("a").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
  var pullNumber = $(this).attr("target");    
  $("#div"+pullNumber).show().siblings(".targetDiv").hide();    
});
```

**CSS**

```
.buttons .selected {
  color: red;
}

.targetDiv{
  display: none;
}

div:nth-of-type(2){
  display:block;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/5254/)

**NEW UPDATE**

Also be sure you either include your script at the bottom of the page, or you can wrap all of your JS in **AND** that you are including jquery before the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     //JS code
    $("a").click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
      var pullNumber = $(this).attr("target");    
      $("#div"+pullNumber).show().siblings(".targetDiv").hide();    
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: no @jmore009 its still not working can you try this on your localhost instead of using it on fiddle may be then you'll see the problem

Comment: @Darkknight have you included Jquery? from your script up there it doesnt look like you have. You need to link to jquery above your `<script></script>` tags

Comment: no @jmore009  nothing is happeing when i click on options you dont try this on jfiddle just create a simple page then check it out

Comment: yeah you are right ,I havnt included any thing can you tell me which script do i have to add for this please paste it here !!

Comment: @Darkknight just copy exactly what I added at the bottom there and replace your current code inside `<head></head>`

Comment: good its working fine , but one thing is that its not showing bydefault red color of option 1 .On page load option 1 must be selected in red color

Comment: @Darkknight yeah look at my fiddle, just add `.selected` to the first option manually so it displays on page load

Comment: i am using this .buttons .selected {
  color: red;
}  on css but its showing all content on page load but i want content of 1st option only on page load and option must be selected in red

Comment: @Darkknight look at my fiddle and copy my HTML and CSS exactly how I have them

Comment: Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4
Lorum Ipsum 1     its showing this bydefault and option 1 color is black . dont run it on js fiddle run it on localhost then you'll see

Comment: @Darkknight i already know why thats happening, you're not adding my css and you're not adding `.selected` to the first item. I've tried this locally and it works fine. Look at my fiddle and copy **exactly** what i've done [http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/5255/](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/5255/)

Comment: done you are right color problem is solved but still content of 1st div is not showing .May be this is beacause in my original webpage there are somay divs and in your code i am using div:nth-of-type(2){
  display:block;
}  can you apply some other identity to this that makes it unique from other divs present in my original webpage

Comment: Great. Yeah you can just add `#div1{display:block;}` - or the `id` of your first div - to your CSS. That should do it. If this is all set now can you check it off as resolved?

Comment: great mr. JMORE you've completely helped me out thanx :)